# How do I hide my favorited tweets?

Tags: twitter, privacy

I recently discovered that Twitter will sometimes show tweets I've favorited to my followers. Personally, I would like to keep my favorited tweets private.

**How can I prevent my favorited tweets from appearing in my followers' timelines?**

Answer (score 1):

Protecting your account will hide liked tweets from non-followers, but there is no way to hide them from your account or from followers' timelines.

However, a solution may be this service:

> It’s a Web service called FavGuard, which connects to your Twitter account and serves as a sort of intermediary between your favoriting decisions and your public persona. Whenever you favorite a tweet, FavGuard stores that favorite and unfavorites the tweet for you. The service promises that “You will always have 0 favorites.”

https://www.dailydot.com/debug/favguard-hides-twitter-favorites/